# use riverpod in custom hooks

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I want to create a custom `useMyAccount` hook in my application, that should return a watcher or my account.

I am using riverpod to manage the account state.

But this code does not work:

```dart
StateNotifierProvider<MyAccountProvider, MyAccount?>? useMyAccount(WidgetRef ref) {
  return ref.watch(myAccountProvider);
}
```

I know that there is the package `hooks_riverpod` and I am using it, but (contrary to the docs and examples) they removed the `useProvider` hook in the latest version and for some reason whenever I use `WidgetRef ref` as a param for the hook, the type `BaseProvider` is always added to my return type.

How can I create a hook that watches and returns my account?